# Find which line point belongs to - Sorting matrices corresponding

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have a geometric point data of TWO lines in Matlab. I'm exporting them to another program which makes a spline through the points. It calculates for example temperature at random points of the spline and sends back to Matlab.

Now I have this data and I have no idea which line the temperature belongs to. But I do get the coordinates of the new points. So I need to determine which line the points belong to and then use that information to split the temperature vector in two.

Here is a code generating an 'example' to work with.

```
% Known geometric point data which is read by 3rd program.
x1 = 0:0.05:1;      y1 = -sin(x1.*(4.*pi))./6;
x2 = 0:0.05:1;      y2 =  sin(x2.*(pi));

% 3rd program makes spline from given points.
xx1 = 0:0.075:1;     xx2 = [0:0.1:1];
yy1 = spline(x1,y1,xx1);
yy2 = spline(x2,y2,xx2);
XY = [xx1, xx2; yy1, yy2]; 
[Y,I]=sort(XY(1,:));

% The program gives me DAT file with the 'new' coordinates of the new
% points. But the line-up of the points are random. In this example I've 
% merged the coordinates of the two lines mixed them by sorting the X
% coordinates.
% The program gives me, for example, the temperature at these points in
% same order as the new coordinates. But now I'll need to know which line
% they belong to.

COORDINATE = XY(:,I);
TEMPERATURE = [COORDINATE(1,:); rand(1,length(COORDINATE))];
```

Goal:

1. Determine which points of COORDINATES belong to [x1,y1] or [x2,y2].
2. Split TEMPERATURE to [xx1; T1] and [xx2; T2] corresonding to #1.

Note that the two lines will never cross each other. But they don't necessary have the same x-spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is to do spline interpolation on the x coordinates in your DAT file in MATLAB and compare the result y coordinates to the ones in your DAT file.

```
% get xy coordinates
xi = COORDINATE(1,:);
yi = COORDINATE(2,:);
% spline interpolation for two lines of every x
yi1 = spline(x1,y1,xi);
yi2 = spline(x2,y2,xi);
% compare y coordinates
d1 = abs(yi1 - yi);
d2 = abs(yi2 - yi);
belongToLine1 = d1 <= d2;
belongToLine2 = d1 >= d2;
% plot
plot(COORDINATE(1,belongToLine1),COORDINATE(2,belongToLine1),'ob-');
hold on;
plot(COORDINATE(1,belongToLine2),COORDINATE(2,belongToLine2),'or-');
hold off
legend('line1','line2');
```

[image]

another option (which does not require interpolation but is limited) is to compute pairwise distances between your original points and the points in your DAT file:

```
% number of first line original points
n1 = length(x1);
% computing pairwise distance between the splines and original points
xy = [x1,x2;y1,y2]';
D = pdist2(COORDINATE',xy);
% find closest pair indexes
[~,idx] = min(D,[],2);
% determine membership
belongToLine1 = idx <= n1;
belongToLine2 = ~belongToLine1;
% plot
plot(COORDINATE(1,belongToLine1),COORDINATE(2,belongToLine1),'ob-');
hold on;
plot(COORDINATE(1,belongToLine2),COORDINATE(2,belongToLine2),'or-');
hold off
legend('line1','line2');
```

[image]